# Is there a good iTunes replacement that works with the iPhone?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, 64-bit, itunes, iphone

Is there a good iTunes replacement that works with the iPhone?

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://superuser.com/questions/64230/replacement-for-itunes-windows-7-64

Comment: It may be... although mine is specifically about the iPhone not the iPod.  Up to y'all...

Comment: You should define what features you are looking if this is not a duplicate. Do you want something that just syncs music or something that syncs everything (contacts, pictures, etc.)?

Comment: However you go about it, the iPhone (unlink the classic iPod) uses the HFS file system internally and you *WILL* need some components of iTunes.

Answer (score 3):

To follow up from my comment to @penlite's answer.

From the [Media Monkey Wiki](http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Guide_to_ipod_sync):

> It is possible to sync certain iPods without iTunes installed. The iPod touch, iPhone, iPod classic, and iPod nano 3rd/4th generation all require certain iTunes components to be installed to sync to them. These files are usually located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support and you could uninstall iTunes as long as you kept the files at the location above. However, there are disadvantages to not keeping iTunes – for example, you can't update the device firmware or restore it without iTunes. You will also not be able to sync pictures or video without iTunes since MediaMonkey currently does not handle these file types.

So whatever program you do settle on, you are still going to have to have iTunes installed.

Answer (score 1):

[Mediamonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is pretty good

Comment: I would have suggested this too, but you still need iTunes installed see here - http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/Guide_to_ipod_sync

Answer (score 0):

[foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) + [foo_dop](http://yuo.be/ipod.php)
(require some iTunes dependencies too)

Answer (score 0):

[doubletwist](http://lifehacker.com/5380478/is-doubletwist-a-real-itunes-alternative) claims to support iphone. See [here](http://www.doubletwist.com/dt/Home/Help.dt#supporteddevices) for supported devices. NB beta software

Answer (score 0):

Most programs that are able to communicate with Apple's gadgets still do require iTunes installed, thus my recommendation to folks who are sick and tired of messing up their systems with iTunes and all the annoyances that go with it:

Install **[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)**, set up a 'disposable' virtual Windows machine with iTunes and keep your real system safe and well out of reach from the Apple's fangs.